# Make some chars of a variable in bold text

Tags: javascript, text, substring

I would like to know how its possible to change the style of some chars of a variable in javascript.
For example:

```
var example = 'Hello World';
```

I would like from char H until L to return in bold text and the rest to be in normal.

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: I tried this but seems not working : example.substring(0,2).style.color='#f00';

Comment: "From H to L" You have 3 L's in your string. You can do that with <b>string</b> or CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you could have specified what 'L' you are talking about.
2. a string var just store some characters, not style. The style is made with html/css, not javascript
3. you can find what you want on internet but here is a sample of html/css with bold text

```css
.boldText {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<span class="boldText">Hel</span>lo World
```

4. don't be afraid of down votes, it's because you should show us what you tried before asking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you Apolo :) . Itried this example.substring(0,2).style.color='#f00';

Comment: the style attribute is for HTMLElements. You can get HTMLElements via `document.getElement[...]` methods. Example with my code : `document.getElementsByClassName("boldText")[0].style.color='#F00';` it will set the bold text red.

Comment: Thank you buddy , this is exactly what i am searching of

Answer (score 0):

You want to have them **bold** in your HTML, so:

```
example = "<b>Hell</b>o World";
```

Comment: Note (From : [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b)) : `Historically, the <b> element was meant to make text boldface. Styling information has been deprecated since HTML4, so the meaning of the <b> element has been changed.` and `If there is no semantic purpose on using the <b> element, using css property font-weight with bold value would be a better choice for making text bold.`